# Как можно сверстать данный блок?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Ребята, помогите пожалуйста. Как можно сверстать данный блок?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какой именно из блоков на вашей картинке "данный" ?

Comment: @Инквизитор картинки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К примеру могу [такой вариант](https://codepen.io/kostyabushuev/pen/KKKgNGJ) предложить. Его не сложно будет заадаптировать для мобильных устройств.

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.img-2,
.img-3 {
  max-width: 400px;
}

.img-1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.img-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: -100px;
}

.img-3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="img-1" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/05/02/21/50/home-office-336378_960_720.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="img-2" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/05/02/21/49/home-office-336373_960_720.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="img-3" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/26/13/09/cup-of-coffee-1280537_960_720.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```